# Is it possible to programmatically log in a user with Azure AD B2C?

Tags: asp.net, azure, signalr, azure-ad-b2c

I am contemplating switching to Azure AD B2C for Identity for our application. Currently we are just using ASP.NET Core local username/passwords.

My application has a simulation mode that is used for training purposes. During a simulation, we login a user as if they were logged in by themselves. The application allows the user to be logged in on more than one device. When the user is logged on a device during a simulation, they can observe in real time their activity while the simulation user works. We achieved this by having an alternate login mechanism that allowed the exchange of a secret and IP address filter to ensure that simulator logins are only allowed from simulator server machines on our network.

I'm trying to figure out how to do something similar with Azure AD B2C. I will never have the user credentials. I need an alternate means of granting user access to the system. Is this something possible?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can create service principals instead of users for which you can [grant permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-web-application?tabs=app-reg-preview#grant-permissions) to access your application.

In your simulation, instead of performing the normal user login, you could perform a [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) and use that token for all authenticated requests.